# PyCharm, не удается запустить дебаггер

Tags: python

Вот код:

```
def total(initial=5, *numbers, **keywords):
    count = initial
    for number in numbers:
        count += number
    for key in keywords:
        count += keywords[key]
    return count


print(total(10, 1, 2, 3, vegetables=50, fruits=100))
```

При запуске выдает:

```
pydev debugger: process 2888 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 183.4886.43)
166

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Что делать? Хотел посмотреть как работает алгоритм пошагово.

Comment: Уже решил, спасибо всем

Comment: Поделитесь, пожалуйста, Вашим решением. Вы можете оставить ответ на свой же вопрос. Возможно, это кому-то поможет в будущем.